# Python Dask module error .. AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python-3.x, dask-dataframe

I am trying to learn how to use dask module in order to overcome a memory problem on a script. Whilst I was reading a csv and creating a dask dataframe from it, I got the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 147, in _strip_protocol
    if path.startswith("file://"):

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

here's my code:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as ddf
'''Read .csv straight to list'''  
with open (wd+inputfilename+extension_csv, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    df = ddf.read_csv(f)   #data here is a dask pandas dataframe
```

Any help on this?

thanks.

Comment: Any resolution with this?

Answer (score 0):

So the `dask.dataframe` `read_csv` function takes a filename, not a file handle.

Your code should be:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as ddf
df = ddf.read_csv(wd+inputfilename+extension_csv)
```

I don't believe you need the `reader = csv.reader(f)` line (which isn't imported anyway)?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all :)